# Unable to mount volume: "Permission Denied", on second account

Tags: permissions, mount, ssd

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
I have 2 user accounts, named y and z. I use one of them for fun stuff, and the other one for school.

I can mount my 1 TB unencrypted external ssd with legally obtained anime perfectly fine on one account, but on the other it says `You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "1d98a312-d7d8-4078-954c-5e73206e925d"`

I can perfectly `sudo ls /media/z/1d98a312-d7d8-4078-954c-5e73206e925d/` and get the list of files.

Idk why I cannot do that without sudo. Its stupid. Anybody can mount the ssd using a Live USB, why does it have to be like that.

On the y account it works, and on the z account it doesn't. The y account was created at installation, the z one using the settings utility.

Comment: This can all be configured. See `man udisks`

Comment: If you add an entry for your drive to `/etc/fstab`, you can allow any user to `mount` the drive. Read `man fstab mount`.